# How to speed up ffmpeg when encoding a single image with audio?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I use `ffmpeg` to mix an audio file with a single photo to make a video with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image -i audio -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage \
-c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest video
```

Since it is a single photo, I expected a quick process, but it works with `speed=2x`, which means it takes half of the duration of the audio.

I wonder if there is a faster approach to put a static image as the background of an audio file to build a video?

Comment: Add `-preset veryfast`

Comment: Try using `-framerate 1` input option with `-r 25` output option, and make sure your log doesn't show `using cpu capabilities: none!`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use the `-preset ultrafast` output option when encoding with libx264, libx264rgb, libx265.
- Check that your log does not show `using cpu capabilities: none!` when encoding with libx264.
- Use a low `-framerate` input option for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1). If your device/player/video sharing platform does not like the low frame rate then increase the `-framerate` value it until it works or add the `-r` output option with a normal frame rate such as `-r 25`.
- If your output container format supports the input audio format then [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) it with `-c:a copy` instead of re-encoding.
- See if [hardware encoding/decoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) is an option for you.

Example for video that should be compatible with most players:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i image -i audio -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -vf format=yuv420p -r 25 -shortest output.mp4
```

Slightly faster version for uploading to video sharing platforms (but I only confirmed this works on YouTube):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i image -i audio -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -c:a copy -vf format=yuv420p -r 5 -shortest output.mkv
```

Comment: @Googlebot 2-3x from image to video isn't much. You're taking a single image and making a video from it that consists of many frames, so it's not really a fair comparison. As for the audio, if you are re-encoding it may increase in size due compression artifacts. In addition there is some muxer overhead. I made the answer thinking speed was your priority according to the question. There are some things you can do to reduce the size (slower `-preset` and longer `-g` for example), but it will slow down the process. It is a tradeoff.

Comment: sorry, I deleted my comment, as I experimented. `-crf 18` and `-r 5` were very useful. I found a peculiar behaviour for `-preset`. I found the optimum condition with `preset veryfast`, small file with reasonable speed. The file size was smaller than `-preset fast`.

Comment: @Googlebot Depending on the input image, using `-crf 0` may be faster, and maybe even a little smaller. Perhaps insignificantly so, but worth a try.